# SQL Server 2008 on a separate machine is very slow

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have an application which gets the data from a MS SQL database residing on a server in the headquarter over an internet connection.

Now the problem is that the data is pretty large which makes the query to take large time to transfer the data from the head quarter to the client.

Does SQL provide anything method to speed up queries if your application is geographically separated from the database (e.g. zipping up the data before it starts to transfer) ?

Comment: Also we are connecting to the far-apart database using the connection string. Can anyone comment if we create a web service or anything like that, will it improve the overall performance?

Comment: If you pull large data you pull large data. How do you get the idea inefficient encoding (xml is more verbose than tds) will improove performance= As the answer says -  dont transfer large amounts of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following quotes from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947489/c-compress-sql-server-2005-query-results) might provide you with some pointers.

> There is never a reason to return a
>   large result to start with. For those
>   particular scenarios that need large
>   amounts of data shipped to the client,
>   there are better solutions than T-SQL
>   queries (log shipping, service broker,
>   replication).

and

> You have a couple options that I am
>   aware of:
>
> 1. Use a third party tool like SQLNitro.
> 2. Move to Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 where they have made
>      various TCP stack improvements, as
>      outlined here: Appendix A: A Closer
>      Look - Examining the Enhancements in
>      Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server
>      2008 That Enable Faster Performance

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not only determined by the bandwidth, the latency is also a very strong factor here. Try to minimize the number of requests. You could combine some queries, to give two (or more) resultsets.

Comment: It's basically a single query/resultset which the client side requires from the database. But that one query takes ages.